# .Net size of a linked list

Tags: .net

How can i find the size (num of elements) of a linked list using a function in F#?

I would like to find the size of linked lists like the following:

```
type rNumber = Integer of int;;
type lists = Nil | Link of (rNumber * (lists ref));;

let list1 = Link(3, ref (Link(2), ref Nil);
let list2 = Link(6, ref (Link(4), ref Nil);
let list3 = Link(9, ref (Link(6), ref Nil);
```

Comment: If you are using standard F# Lists then you can just use `List.length`.  What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not, it's a custom linked list

Comment: So what have you tried to implement length - I am guessing this is homework so I don't want to just give away the answer.  Also, the answer will depend on How `Link` is defined so it would be good to add that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the pattern matching only knows about the Standard .Net list.  If your `Link` is just a tuple this will work

```
let rec length a = 
    match a with
    |Link(_,ref Nil) 0 -> 1
    |Link(_,t) -> 1+(length t)
```

**EDIT:**

Now we know how `Link` works this should do the trick

```
let rec length a = 
    match a with
    |Nil -> 0
    |Link(_,t) -> 1+(length (!t))
```

The `!` is required because you use `lists ref` in your definition which isn't particularly functional.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this and see how it works because I don't really understand the logic behind it still.

Comment: Basically the length of the list is 1 + the number of elements after the first element

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.  Unfortunately it didn't work for me, but I'll try to figure it out.  F# is still new to me so I'm not too comfortable with it yet.

Comment: Without knowing what Link does - this is the best I can do.

Comment: Wow, I must say you know what you are doing.  I really appreciate all of your time and help.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to fully understand this, this is taking 1 plus the number of elements after the first element in the list (which is head or length (!t))?

Comment: This is correct - but the remaining part is `Tail` not `Head`

Comment: For example, in order to find the sum of the elements in the link list is as follows for a standard list: let rec sum list =
 match list with
 | [] -> 0
 | head :: tail -> head + sum tail  but in the case of Link, what is head?

Comment: @JohnOriely - the first element in the pair - the part that I ignored with the `_`

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I was trying to compute the sum of the values, but am stuck

Comment: Replace `_` with `a` and `1` with `a` in my code and all will work fine.

Comment: I just updated the first two lines of my initial code where declaring Link.  I accidentally had an incorrect type so when I try to replace _ with a 1 and 1 with a in your code, it gives me incompatible type error.